# Colored tabular - line not showing

Tags: tables, color

```
\begin{tabular}{| p{10cm} | c |}
\hline
& \\
{\bf Requirement:} & {\bf Categorie:} \\
& \\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{orange}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{orange}{\bf Could Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{orange}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

One of the `\hline` commands isn't comming through? See my picture for the error.

Comment: Try to zoom into the PDF -- I think the line is there, but this is a well-known PDF viewer issue

Comment: wow, I generated the PDF, now I do see the line indeed. Thank you! @ChristianHupfer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known viewer issue, as also pointed out by @ChristianHupfer. In this case, you can increase the `\arrayrulewidth` or just open with another viewer.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{| p{10cm} | c |}
\hline
& \\
{\bf Requirement:} & {\bf Categorie:} \\
& \\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{orange}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{orange}{\bf Could Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{orange}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem. In the following code, I have loaded `nicematrix` (and unloaded `colortbl`) and replaced the environment `{tabular}` with the environment `{NiceTabular}` with the key `color-inside` (alias `colortbl-like`) which means that there will be color instructions within the tabular.

You have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{| p{10cm} | c |}[color-inside]
\hline
& \\
{\bf Requirement:} & {\bf Categorie:} \\
& \\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{green}{\bf Must Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{green}}\\
\hline
& {\cellcolor{orange}}\\
text & {\cellcolor{orange}{\bf Could Have}} \\
& {\cellcolor{orange}}\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

*Remark* `\bf` is considered as deprecated in LaTeX and one should use `\bfseries` instead.

[image: Output of the first code]