# Table wont show all borders

Tags: tables, border

I have made the following table:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue!25}$M_{\delta}$ & \cellcolor{blue!25}$t_{go}^{s}$ [sec] & \cellcolor{blue!25}\text{Miss Distance [m]} \\ \hline
     -100 & 0.5274 &  1.40153 \\ \hline
     -150 & 0.4664 &  1.03992 \\ \hline
     -200 & 0.4360 &  0.85460 \\ \hline
     -250 & 0.4216 &  0.74391 \\ \hline
     -300 & 0.4172 &  0.67290 \\ \hline
     -350 & 0.4179 &  0.62575 \\ \hline
     -400 & 0.4190 &  0.59338 \\ \hline
     -450 & 0.4183 &  0.56994 \\ \hline
     -500 & 0.4161 &  0.55187 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

However, when I run the code the table looks as following:
[image]

I noticed that when I compile the borders sometimes appear and sometimes not.

Is there a way that I can make sure all the borders appear?

Thank you

Comment: This might be a viewer issue. Do the lines show up if you magnify the output in your viewer? Related: [Colored tabular - line not showing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304575/134144)

Comment: Anyway, since all cells of the first row have the same colour, you should use the shorter syntax: `\rowcolor{blue!25} $M_{\delta}$ &$t_{go}^{s}$ [sec] & \text{Miss Distance [m]}`

Answer (score 2):

this is "extended" comment. consider [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) comment, adding some small changes in column type and array  stretching, your table looks like:

[image]

above image is generated by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array} 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}             % <---
    \begin{tabular}{| >{$}c<{$} | c | c |}  % <---
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!25}
    M_{\delta}    & $t_{go}^{s}$ [sec] & Miss Distance [m]    \\ \hline
     -100 & 0.5274  &  1.40153 \\ \hline
     -150 & 0.4664  &  1.03992 \\ \hline
     -200 & 0.4360  &  0.85460 \\ \hline
     -250 & 0.4216  &  0.74391 \\ \hline
     -300 & 0.4172  &  0.67290 \\ \hline
     -350 & 0.4179  &  0.62575 \\ \hline
     -400 & 0.4190  &  0.59338 \\ \hline
     -450 & 0.4183  &  0.56994 \\ \hline
     -500 & 0.4161  &  0.55187 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ben, any news?

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem. In the following code, I have loaded `nicematrix` (and unloaded `colortbl`) and replaced the environment `{tabular}` with the environment `{NiceTabular}` with the key `color-inside` (alias `colortbl-like`) which means that there will be color instructions within the tabular.

You have directly the expected output. The rules won't seem to vanish, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{| >{$}c<{$} | c | c |}[color-inside] 
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!25}
    M_{\delta}    & $t_{go}^{s}$ [sec] & Miss Distance [m]    \\ \hline
     -100 & 0.5274  &  1.40153 \\ \hline
     -150 & 0.4664  &  1.03992 \\ \hline
     -200 & 0.4360  &  0.85460 \\ \hline
     -250 & 0.4216  &  0.74391 \\ \hline
     -300 & 0.4172  &  0.67290 \\ \hline
     -350 & 0.4179  &  0.62575 \\ \hline
     -400 & 0.4190  &  0.59338 \\ \hline
     -450 & 0.4183  &  0.56994 \\ \hline
     -500 & 0.4161  &  0.55187 \\ \hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Moreover, `{NiceTabular}` has a key `hvlines` to draw all the rules in the tabular. Hence, you have the same output with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{>{$}c<{$} c c }[color-inside,hvlines]     
    \rowcolor{blue!25}
    M_{\delta}    & $t_{go}^{s}$ [sec] & Miss Distance [m]    \\ 
     -100 & 0.5274  &  1.40153 \\ 
     -150 & 0.4664  &  1.03992 \\ 
     -200 & 0.4360  &  0.85460 \\ 
     -250 & 0.4216  &  0.74391 \\ 
     -300 & 0.4172  &  0.67290 \\ 
     -350 & 0.4179  &  0.62575 \\ 
     -400 & 0.4190  &  0.59338 \\ 
     -450 & 0.4183  &  0.56994 \\ 
     -500 & 0.4161  &  0.55187 \\ 
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```