# After implementing xcolor, simple table becomes buggy

Tags: tables, color

When I am making a table with colored first raw using xcolor for my thesis, vertical line in first raw behaves differently in random (as visible in image "with color"). When I avoid coloring (just uncommenting "\usepackage[table]{xcolor}" and "\rowcolor{gray}") it is behaving normal without any problem (as visible in image "without color"). What is the problem here and what is simplest and effective solution?. Why some vertical lines (column separator) are darker than others?.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| }
\hline
\rowcolor{gray}
  Hours of incubation  & pH 5.0 & pH 6.0 & pH 7.0 & pH 7.5 & pH 8.0 & pH 8.5 & pH 9.0 & pH 10 \\ \hline 
12 & 0.00 & 0.0238 & 0.4036 & 0.4397 & 0.4493 & 0.4349 & 0.3191 & 0.005 \\\hline
24  &   0.00  &     0.1319 &    1.7929 &    1.8368 &    1.8629 &    1.8032 &    1.4087 &    0.035\\\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: with color]`[image: without color]

Comment: This is a well known issue and most likely due to your pdf viewer. If you zoom in, the missing lines will appear.

Comment: See also: [Colored tabular - line not showing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304575/134144), [Colored row not showing demarcated cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342161/134144), [Solution for disappearing table/cell borders with \rowcolor in the PDF viewer depending on zoom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490663/134144) and the many other similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known issue, mostly connected to your PDF-reader.
If you zoom in far enough, you will probably see the lines again.

In addition, LaTeX is focused on good typography, and in good typography  horizontal lines and colour should not be mixed in tables. Also vertical lines should not be used.

Read the documentation to the package [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to learn how to build good looking tabulars.

If you insist on using colour and lines simultaneously, I suggest that you take a closer look at [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), which handles cell background colour and rules. Below is the source for such tabular. I have also included two other tabulars, using `tabular`, `booktabs`and `array`, and without mixing horizontal rules and colours, and without vertical rules. When you are using `\rowcolor` you should not remove the tabular's side bearings (`@{}`, because then `@{} do not remove the colour from the side bearing:

### calstable

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cals}

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}[c]

% Defining column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(1.5\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/9\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.8pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}

\def\gray{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{gray!30}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1
\thead{\bfseries\footnotesize
\brow
    \gray\alignC\cell{\vfil Hours of incubation }
    \cell{\vfil pH 5.0}
    \cell{\vfil pH 6.0}
    \cell{\vfil pH 7.0}
    \cell{\vfil pH 7.5}
    \cell{\vfil pH 8.0}
    \cell{\vfil pH 8.5}
    \cell{\vfil pH 9.0}
    \cell{\vfil pH 10}\gray
\erow
\mdseries
}
\tfoot{%
    \lastrule\nointerlineskip%
    %\textit{\strut Some table caption%
    %}%
    \par%
    }
% R2 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{12}
    \cell{0.00}
    \cell{0.0238}
    \cell{0.4036}
    \cell{0.4397}
    \cell{0.4493}
    \cell{0.4349}
    \cell{0.3191}
    \cell{0.005}
\erow
% R3 Body
\brow
    \alignC\cell{24}
    \cell{0.00}
    \cell{0.1319}
    \cell{1.7929}
    \cell{1.8368}
    \cell{1.8629}
    \cell{1.8032}
    \cell{1.4087}
    \cell{0.035}
\erow
\makeatletter

\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Alternatives

Below is also a tabular using `\rowcolor`, but without rules, and a `booktabs`-tabular. Be aware that both those tabulars are wider than the `\linewidth`, but I assumed you are using different margins in your document. If not, try using `\footnotesize` to reduce the width:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}


\begin{document}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{2cm}cccccccr}
\rowcolor{gray!30}
Hours of incubation  & pH 5.0 & pH 6.0 & pH 7.0 & pH 7.5 & pH 8.0 & pH 8.5 & pH 9.0 & pH 10 \\
12 & 0.00 & 0.0238 & 0.4036 & 0.4397 & 0.4493 & 0.4349 & 0.3191 & 0.005 \\
24  &   0.00  &     0.1319 &    1.7929 &    1.8368 &    1.8629 &    1.8032 &    1.4087 &    0.035\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

{%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering}p{2cm}cccccccr@{}}

\toprule
Hours of incubation  & pH\,5.0 & pH\,6.0 & pH\,7.0 & pH\,7.5 & pH\,8.0 & pH\,8.5 & pH\,9.0 & pH\,10\\\midrule
12 & 0.00 & 0.0238 & 0.4036 & 0.4397 & 0.4493 & 0.4349 & 0.3191 & 0.005 \\
24  &   0.00  &     0.1319 &    1.7929 &    1.8368 &    1.8629 &    1.8032 &    1.4087 &    0.035\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding the cals package: did you ever tried to add a color in a cell? e.g. with `\cell{\color{green}body 1.1}`?

Comment: It not only colors the rest of the table but also all following text. And it is a problem as it indicates that it doesn't use color groups correctly. I wouldn't trust a package which contains such an error.

Comment: cells are groups, add e.g. \bfseries in a group and you will see. But the package doesn't use color safe boxing commands.

Comment: Not *we", *you* should issue a bug report. I don't use or recommend the package in answers.

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem. With its environment `{NiceTabular}`, the rules won't seem to disappear, whatever PDF viewer you use, at all the levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccccc}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
\rowcolor{gray}
Hours of incubation & pH 5.0 & pH 6.0 & pH 7.0 & pH 7.5 & pH 8.0 & pH 8.5 & pH 9.0 & pH 10 \\ 
12 & 0.00 & 0.0238 & 0.4036 & 0.4397 & 0.4493 & 0.4349 & 0.3191 & 0.005 \\
24 & 0.00 & 0.1319 & 1.7929 & 1.8368 & 1.8629 & 1.8032 & 1.4087 & 0.035 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: +1: A very nice result that (after installing the updated package) required only minimal changes to my code: replacing "tabular" with "nicetable" in \begin{tabular} and \endtabular}. Still get a warning "! LaTeX3 Error: The key property '.str_set:N' is unknown.", but this doesn't seem to cause any serious upset if the warning is ignored and compilation proceeds.

Comment: @Jason Whyte. Good remark. Indeed, I have used in the code of `nicematrix` the key `.str_set:N` which is available only in recent versions of the LaTeX kernel (≥ 2021-10-30). However, I will use a workaround in the next release of `nicematrix` and it will be compatible with (for instance) the actual version of Overleaf.

Comment: @FPantigny I solved the problem through stumbling upon this Stack Exchange question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576918/mismatched-latex-support-files-detected and following the advice in a comment of running (in mac terminal) fmtutil-sys --all. Compiles with no problem now, so maybe this will save you some work.