# How to solve "Mismatched LaTeX support files" problem permanently

Tags: updating, format-files, texlive-2020

### Background

I updated my TeX Live installation on my Mac a while ago and got the error

`LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.`

I found a solution at [Mismatched LaTeX support files detected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576918/mismatched-latex-support-files-detected).  As far as I understand it (which isn't very far), there are system formats and local formats, and TeX Live is updating the wrong one.  The fix is to update the formats.

Using `fmtutil-user --all` worked for me.  It spewed out a load of stuff, then output

```
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /Users/<user>/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/dvilualatex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /Users/<user>/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/dvilualatex.fmt installed.
```

I don't know what this tells me, but my TeX Live preferences has TeX programs set at `/Library/TeX/texbin`, which seems to be a link to `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin`.

### Problem

Every time I update TeX Live, I have to apply the solution again.

### Question

Is there a way to make TeX Live use the correct formats permanently so that I don't have to keep running `fmtutil-user --all` after every TeX Live update?

---

### Extra information

[The original solution has a comment by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576918/mismatched-latex-support-files-detected#comment1452441_576918) to

> check if you have some local formats around which hide the system formats. (with eg `kpsewhich --all --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`)

When I did that, it output

```
/Users/<user>/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
```

but I don't know what that's telling me.

Comment: Try to delete the formats in `/Users/<user>/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`, perhaps run a `fmtutil-sys --all` (sys not user!),  and then never run fmutil-user again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. I put all those format files in the bin, then ran `fmtutil-sys --all` – sys not user :) – and when it was done, it said: 

`fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/luatex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/luatex.fmt installed.
TeX::LSR: ls-R file not writable, skipping: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/ls-R
Cannot write ls-R in /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var. at /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/mktexlsr.pl line 583.`

Do I need use `sudo`?

Comment: yes you need sudo if you originally installed the system one under sudo

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I used the installer to install it, so I'm not sure – although I did have to input my password, so I guess the installer was using sudo. The `sys` version spewed out a lot more stuff this time, ending with `fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
fmtutil [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 54
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 59
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0`, which looks better. Now all I have to do is wait for TeXLive to be updated so I can check that this has fixed it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is still not quite clear *why* these local formats appear when updating, so there is no definitive solution so far.  I will update this answer when the cause is found out; meanwhile these are the steps to solve the problem (which should occur at most when `l3kernel` is updated, which is not *that* often):

#### TL;DR

First run from the command line:

- `kpsewhich --all --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` if you are using pdfLaTeX
- `kpsewhich --all --engine=luahbtex lualatex.fmt` if you are using LuaLaTeX
- `kpsewhich --all --engine=xetex xelatex.fmt` if you are using XeLaTeX

then look at the output.  If you have **two** lines of output, looking like this:

```latex
/home/<user>/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
```

then delete the file from the path that starts `/home/<user>/.texlive<year>` (or `/Users/<user>/Library` if you're on Mac) and the problem should be gone!

---

#### The problem persists

If you are still getting the error:

- check if you are using the correct `kpsewhich` call for the engine you are using;
- check that the output of the `kpsewhich` call returns only one line;
- if you are using LaTeX-dev. then add `-dev` to the `.fmt` file in the `kpsewhich` call, for example, `pdflatex-dev.fmt` and check for the two lines as above;

If nothing works, read on.

---

#### Slightly longer version

This error message was intentionally added mid-2020 after `expl3` was integrated into the LaTeX kernel because it happens quite often that `tlmgr` generates the local `.fmt` file.  This `.fmt` file is not updated, thus frozen with an old version of LaTeX (with an old version of `expl3` preloaded), and then when you update, the two different versions are incompatible<sup>[1]</sup>.

The error message says (along these lines):

```latex
! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX3)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX3)        
(LaTeX3)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX3)        is dated 2021-02-18, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX3)        at least 2021-05-11.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
                                         %
?
```

Which means that the `expl3` that different versions of `expl3` were detected.  If you are running from the command line, you can type `H <enter>` at the prompt above, then the error message may show two different texts, depending on some heuristics.  By *far* the most common is:

```
The cause seems to be an old format file in the user tree.
LaTeX found these files:
 - /home/<user>/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt 
 - /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt 
Try deleting the file in the user tree then run LaTeX again.
```

which points to the two files I mentioned above (this error message is actually just a wrapper to that `kpsewhich` call).

It is possible, however, that the issue is not a stale format file.  In this case, the error help for the error message will read:

```
The most likely causes are:
 - A recent format generation failed;
 - A stray format file in the user tree which needs to be removed or rebuilt;
 - You are running a manually installed version of expl3.sty
   which is incompatible with the version in LaTeX.
```

which are the likely causes for the problem.  In order:

- An error during format generation is *very* unlikely, but you can try running `fmtutil-sys --all` (you may need `sudo` depending how you installed TeX Live) and see if the output shows something suspicious;
- The stray format is the issue described above, but depending how you run LaTeX (namely if you run with `-no-shell-escape`), then it won't be able to run `kpsewhich`;
- [image] You may have manually installed a newer version of `l3kernel` instead of updating LaTeX.  If that's what you want to do, then you have to copy the `l3kernel` files to your local `TEXMF` tree, then run `mktexfmt pdflatex` (or `lualatex` or `xelatex`) to rebuild the LaTeX formats (or `fmtutil-sys --all` to rebuild all).  Rebuilding the formats will then pick up the changes to `l3kernel`.  Note that running `mktexfmt` will create a local `.fmt` file, so you might need to delete (or regenerate) that after an update.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not really incompatible, but it would often lead to a [dark path of debugging](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/781) only to find that the problem was the stale `.fmt` file.