# Update code after package upgrade

Tags: siunitx

When I try to compile some TeX code from a few years ago that relies on the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX3)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX3)        
(LaTeX3)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX3)        is dated 2021-02-18, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX3)        at least 2021-05-11.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.77      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
                                         %
```

The code itself is not relevant; the error can be reproduced by compiling, say, the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI{1}{\s}

\end{document}
```

I have just updated my TeX Live 2021 distribution and furthermore I haven't encountered this error before.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the output of `kpsewhich --all --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`? (assuming you are using pdfTeX)

Comment: `[<username>@localhost test]$ kpsewhich --all --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt
/home/<username>/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: Delete `/home/<username>/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt` and it should work

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: This is in theory a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585664/134574, but that post doesn't have an answer...

Comment: Good point! `:-)`