# Error "Mismatched LaTeX support files detected"

Tags: updating, tlmgr, fmtutil

### Edit

See answer: personal issue with the path not being the correct one.

---

When running lualatex I get the following error message:

```bash
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX3)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX3)        
(LaTeX3)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX3)        is dated 2022-04-10, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX3)        at least 2022-11-02.
```

I already checked the answers for that question (especially [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598609/252672)), but none of it worked, I still get the same error message.

When I run

- `kpsewhich --all --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` I get `/home/(user)/.texlive2022/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`
- `kpsewhich --all --engine=luahbtex lualatex.fmt` I get `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/lualatex.fmt`
- `kpsewhich --all --engine=xetex xelatex.fmt` I get `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt`

And if I run it with the `-dev` extension like `pdflatex-dev.fmt` I get the exact same output with files having the `-dev` extension.

That seems ok to me, so I do not what is wrong.

I also ran `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` and I don’t seem to have an issue.

I am running on that if it is relevant:

```bash
$ tlmgr version 
tlmgr revision 63068 (2022-04-18 07:58:07 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2022
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2022
```

Comment: remove `/home/(user)/.texlive2022/texmf-var/ ` so you use your updated system formats not old ones you made in your account  previously

Comment: deleting those files is also what is suggested in the answer that you link to

Comment: unless you have fixed your sudo path since your last question `sudo fmtutil-sys --all ` will be using the wrong `fmtutil-sys`, don't use sudo or use the full path

Comment: Make sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

based on David Carlisle comments:

- Delete `/home/(user)/.texlive2022/texmf-var/`
- And because I haven’t set the correct path for `sudo fmtutil-sys`, just used the ablosute path  `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/fmtutil-sys --all`.

That worked.