Suddenly not able te render QUARTO document in R beacuse of latex
I suddenly can not render my quarto document in R. Everything was fine and it was able to render, until I wanted to render it again and it did not work. The last thing I did before I rendered it for the last time was removing a line I wrote by using LaTex Math -> Display Math, because when it rendered it did not look good. Since then I am not able to render my document anymore and my deadline is in 3 hours. This is the message I get in my Background Jobs when the render is interrupted.
processing file: file.qmd
output file: file.knit.md
pandoc
to: latex
output-file: file.tex
standalone: true
pdf-engine: xelatex
variables:
graphics: true
tables: true
default-image-extension: pdf
metadata
documentclass: scrartcl
classoption:
- DIV=11
- numbers=noendperiod
papersize: letter
header-includes:
- '\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}'
- '\usepackage{caption}'
- '\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}'
block-headings: true
editor: visual
title: Analyse van de Oppervlaktetemperatuur van de Noordelijke Atlantische Oceaan
subtitle: Het bestuderen en voorspellen van maandelijkse temperatuurdata
running xelatex - 1
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=xelatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
updating tlmgr
updating existing packages
compilation failed- error
LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX)
(LaTeX)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX)        is dated 2024-08-30, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX)        at least 2024-10-09.
For immediate help type H .
...
l.78      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
%
see file.log for more information.
This is the header of my document, I did not change a thing about that. So this header worked perfectly fine before:

editor: visual
format: pdf
title: "Analyse van de Oppervlaktetemperatuur van de Noordelijke Atlantische Oceaan"
subtitle: "Het bestuderen en voorspellen van maandelijkse temperatuurdata"
header-includes:

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}


I also tried to render another document which I knew would be able to render because I did not change it and it was able to render yesterday. Also that document did not render, but because it took too long.
I tried to update Tex but that was not the issue, because it was up to date. Here is what it said:
(base) C:\Users\loubn>tlmgr update --self --all
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr.pl: no self-updates for tlmgr available
tlmgr.pl: no updates available
(base) C:\Users\loubn>tlmgr update --all
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr.pl: no updates available
When I render it to HTML it works perfectly fine, but for my deadline I really need it in pdf format.
I hope someone can come up with a solution, many thanks in advance!

rebuilt the latex formats.

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598609/2388

shouldn't that be tlmgr update --all? you are just telling it to update tlmgr.pl i.e. itself. you want it to update everything.

welcome, by the way. in future: never, ever update you tex installation right be fore a deadline unless you are confident of your backup compilation plan. if your document is not too complex/long, you could try compiling it on overleaf. is tlmgr configured to save backups? if so, you should, at least in theory, be able to roll back the updates.

finally, why are you updating your tex installation as part of the compilation process? (if that is really what's happening? or did you combine multiple logs/outputs?) it really, really isn't a good idea to run tlmgr as an ordinary user unless you installed TeX Live that way (or simply have no choice, but it is still easier not to if you don't have the choice).

It's hard to debug without more information about your system but you really do appear to have some issue involving conflicting package versions, like the error suggests.

compilation failed- error LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected. (LaTeX) Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted! (LaTeX)
(LaTeX) The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format (LaTeX) is dated 2024-08-30, but in your TeX tree the files require (LaTeX) at least 2024-10-09.

It wouldn't surprise me if there was some issue where it thinkings its up to date, but really isn't. specifically, it looks like somehow your format file needs to be regenerated based on the new version but hasn't been. I'd recommend attempting to do a full uninstall, and then re-install. Alternatively you could attempt to install the version that matches the format file, 2024-08-30.

welcome! while the first would probably work, it probably isn't needed. I am not sure the second suggestion is possible and, if it is, it certainly isn't advisable.

actually, the first may well fail if the user is running tlmgr as user and compiling with a tex installation installed as sys.

Thank you for your help! I think it wasn't actually up to date like you said, even though it said it was. I reinstalled LaTeX without uninstalling the previous version, as I was concerned about causing issues. This worked perfectly. After my deadlines are over, I’ll try uninstalling and reinstalling it completely, since while it’s functioning now, it requires additional (unnecessary?) steps to render to PDF—steps that weren’t needed before.

@LoubnaElh as I said above, if you say tlmgr update --all tlmgr.pl you only try to update tlmgr.pl and nothing else. this is why the output says tlmgr.pl: no updates available.

I have faced this problem several times and I suspect that is mainly because RStudio try to update the latex packages too much, mostly because some command was mistyped, so sometimes will fail for some reason, so you may need a  fmtutil-sys --all  or  a fmtutil-user -all. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585664/11604 Note that quarto YAML can deactivate automatic tmlgr updates for your document.
