# Outdated L3 programming layer for expl3.sty

Tags: pdftex, tlmgr, tinytex

Running `pdflatex` with `.TinyTex` I get the following error message:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX3)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX3)        
(LaTeX3)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX3)        is dated 2021-01-09, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX3)        at least 2021-02-18.
```

Weird thing, the message won't change after reinstalling `l3kernel`:

```
tlmgr install --reinstall --with-doc --with-src l3kernel
```

or running

```
tlmgr remove --force l3kernel
tlmgr install l3kernel
```

When only uninstalling `l3kernel`, then I get the error `! LaTeX Error: File 'expl3.sty' not found.` - so the problem is definitely within that package.

Comment: typically this mean that you have some local format shadowing the system format. What do you get from `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex --all pdflatex.fmt` ?

Comment: when running `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex --all pdflatex.fmt` I get `/home/my_name/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It seems that something in March 2021 led to a local format. Found myself one in ~/.texlive2020/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/ ! After deleting it, error gone. However, thank you for your hint to find the second, unwanted tree using kpsewhich. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579759/4736 (comments) as well.

Comment: In my case (running TinyTex in R), I just ran ```tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()``` and restarted R. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as the OP, probably caused by an interrupted update. I fixed it by running this:

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```