# The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format is outdated

Tags: expl3, latex3

I'm submitting my manuscript to a journal. It required me to provide the `.tex` file. Everything is ok when I compile the source file on overleaf or my local texlive. But the submission system failed to generate the target pdf. I got such an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX) Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX) 
(LaTeX) The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX) is dated 2022-10-26, but in your TeX tree the files 
require
(LaTeX) at least 2022-11-02.
```

I found some solutions in [Outdated L3 programming layer for expl3.sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586467/outdated-l3-programming-layer-for-expl3-sty?newreg=77043067b31f4fc2abbb2915b5ebc0bc). These solutions indicate that it's caused by interrupted update or version conflict, but I have no way to fix the submission system.

Are there any other possible causes or I should report this problem to the journal?

Comment: if the journal's compilation fails this way they have to fix it (I assume that you do not have any expl3 files in your submission that could confuse things)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the problem is solved after removing a `.cls`  file using expl3 in the official template. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In my today's case (recognised journal; without problems with the initial manuscript uploaded two months ago, since the problem emerged 2-11-2022), it was enough to remove \usepackage{breqn} that uses experimental expl3. It is not a fix, but I was able to submit the paper.