# Mismatched LaTeX support files detected in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, miktex, biber, texmaker

I have run into an issue while runnung a test code in an attempt to create a bibliography.

Specifications: I am using TeXMaker (Version Texmaker 5.1.4) and MiKTeX (Version (23.12)) on Windows 11 (Version 22H2 (Build 22621.3007)).

Here is what I've done:

In order to run biber via TeXMaker I've created the command biber using the "Edit User Commands" menu provided by TexMaker. Then I used the "Configure Texmaker" Menu to set the entry Bib(la)tex (which is found under the menu point "Commands") to biber %. I then created a file named Testbib.tex containing the test code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
%\bibliography{literatur.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
We have shown statement A \cite{Demtroeder2013}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literatur}]
\end{document}
```

where the file literature.bib is defined by the code

```
@Book{Demtroeder2013,
author = {Wolfgang Demtroeder},
publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
title = {Experimentalphysik 2},
year = {2013},
}
```

Running biber via the command BibTex on the test file in question worked without issues. However, when I subsequently attempt to run the command `pdflatex Testbib` via the command prompt I get the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX)
(LaTeX)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX)        is dated 2023-10-23, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX)        at least 2024-01-04.

For immediate help type H <return>.
```

Interestingly, the pdf file was still created. However, I would like to be able to fix the cause of this error message. [According to this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586467/outdated-l3-programming-layer-for-expl3-sty?newreg=77043067b31f4fc2abbb2915b5ebc0bc) this phenomenon seems to be connected to an issue within the l3 kernel.

I have also run the command

```
kpsewhich --engine=pdftex --all pdflatex.fmt
```

which produced

```
C:/Users/my_name/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/miktex/data/le/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
```

But now I am not sure how to proceed or how to fix this. Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: Try to recreate the formats in the miktex console (user mode)

Comment: btw: the bibliography is unrelated.  Every pdflatex document will show this error if the format is wrong.