# After texlive package update, nothing compiles

Tags: texlive, compilation-error, updating

I updated my packages in texlive 2021 today through the GUI package manager. Afterwards, no document compiles. When trying to compile a basic document with `pdflatex`, I receive the following error:

pdflatex

> ---! c:/Users/.../texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt made by different executable version
> (Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)

When compiling a basic document in `xelatex` with `polyglossia`, I receive the following error message:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

> ! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected. (LaTeX3)
> Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted! (LaTeX3)         (LaTeX3)        The L3
> programming layer in the LaTeX format (LaTeX3)        is dated
> 2021-06-01, but in your TeX tree the files require (LaTeX3)        at
> least 2021-07-12.

Neither compilation produces a log file. Clearly something has gone very wrong, but I wouldn't know what. Any pointers?

Comment: Did you try `fmtutil-sys --all` to remake the formats?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576918/mismatched-latex-support-files-detected/589115.

Comment: check if you have local formats around which interfere

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have no idea how to do that or what to do if I did find anything.

Comment: @Marijn I typed what you suggest in the command prompt now. A lot of stuff happened, and I have no idea what. What does it entail to "remake the formats"?

Comment: type `kpsewhich --all --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` in a command prompt and if it reports two fmts delete the one that is older or looks "local".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It just returned one. Possibly because the command that Marijin suggested fixed it ... ?

Comment: well is it fixed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It appears so. But I have no idea what it did ("remade the formats"), and I'm curious why updating my packages would cause this.

Comment: The format files `.fmt` (like `latex.fmt`, `xelatex.fmt` and many others) contain a precompiled version of the respective kernels that is loaded automatically when compiling a document. Among other things `expl3`, which is frequently updated, is part of the kernel. When you update packages that depend on a `.fmt` file the versions must be in sync. Therefore after a package update that includes such packages the formats should be compiled again. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585664/how-to-solve-mismatched-latex-support-files-problem-permanently for more background.